# Add indent to loguru logs if produced by a nested call of a class

Tags: python-3.x, class, indentation, loguru

I have a python class called `A()`, which has methods.
Classes `B(A)` and `C(A)` inherit from base class `A()`, and have other methods.
I instanciate b = B() into `C`.
If every one of these classes has `loguru` logs in its methods, how can I indent each call level?

For example:

```
class A():       
    def __init__(self):
        pass                      
    def m_a(self):                
        logger.info("this is m_a")
                                                                                  
class B(A):                       
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def m_b(self):                
        logger.info("this is m_b")

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def m_c(self):
        ma = self.m_a()
        logger.info("this is m_c")
        b = B()
        mb = b.m_b()

c = C()
c.m_c()
```

I obtain

```
INFO - this is m_a
INFO - this is m_c
INFO - this is m_a
INFO - this is m_b
```

How can I obtain instead

```
INFO - this is m_a
INFO - this is m_c
INFO -   this is m_a
INFO -   this is m_b
```